# Get value from html button attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following likert scale:

```
 <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
     <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
     <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled style="width:10px">Not<br />Fearsome</a>
     <button id="fear1" type="button" name="gender" class="btn btn-default likert-1" val="0">1</button>
     <button id="fear2" type="button" name="gender" class="btn btn-default likert-2" val="1">2</button>
     <button id="fear3" type="button" name="gender" class="btn btn-default likert-3" val="2">3</button>
     <button id="fear4" type="button" name="gender" class="btn btn-default likert-4" val="3">4</button>
     <button id="fear5" type="button" name="gender" class="btn btn-default likert-5" val="4">5</button>
     <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled style="width:10px">Extremely<br />Fearsome</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I am trying to access the 'val' attribute from a script by using:

```
$('#fear').val($(this).getAttribute('val'));
```

but this does not seem to work.

**Note**: `#fear` is the `id` of a hidden variable

Comment: try `$(this).attr('val')`

Comment: What is not working exactly? In which function are you using this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAttribute` is a standard DOM method but you are trying to call it on a jQuery object.

Either use a standard DOM object:

```
this.getAttribute('val')
```

or use the jQuery attr method:

```
$(this).attr('val')
```

---

Note that `val` is not a valid attribute for the button element. Consider `data-val` instead.

Alternative, avoid adding an extra attribute with redundant information in the first place.

```
$(this).text();
```

Answer (score 2):

none of the element has id "fear", check u have named them like fear1, fear2, fear3 ....

try

```
$(this).attr('val');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `$('#fear').attr('val');`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @DimalChandrasiri, use

```
$(this).attr('val') or $('#fear').attr('val')
```